# Getting "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react2.proptypes.string')" after importing react-native-prompt

Tags: react-native, react-proptypes

I am using the newest version of NPM, the version of exp is 57.0.0. When I add to my code  in render method, I get an error "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react2.proptypes.string')". Without adding  everything works perfect.

Both Prop-Types and React-native-prompt are installed.

I have already tried to write import Prompt from 'prop-types'; instead of writing import Prompt from 'react-native-prompt'; but then I am getting the error that  hasn't been found in Prop-Types.

Any suggestions on how to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some of your code samples? Also, you say you use react-native-prompt, is is some third party lib or the builtin RNT component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PropTypes` moved into separate package. Use `prop-types` package.

`react-native-prompt` use outdated style of prop-types so you have to manually solve it.

go to `/node-modules/react-native-prompt` and edit main files in this way:

```
import { PropTypes } from 'react'
```

the above line is incorrect and must be like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

You have to import PropTypes in this way.

More info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

> **Note:**
>   React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead. We provide a codemod script to automate the conversion.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me :)